# Group by subquery

Tags: oracle, group-by, oracle10g

I have following query

```
Select id, name, add1 || ' ' ||add2 address,
        case 
            when subId =1 then 'Maths'
            else 'Science'
        End,
        nvl(col1, col2) sampleCol
From Student_tbl
Where department = 'Student'
```

I want to group by this query by address as default

I tried

```
Group by add1 ,add2 ,id, name, subId, col1, col2
```

and

```
Group by add1 || ' ' ||add2,id, name,
         case 
            when subId =1 then 'Maths'
            else 'Science'
        End,
        nvl(col1, col2)
```

Both group by returns same result. I am unsure which query is right.
Anybody help me on this?

Comment: Show some sample data, what you are getting, and what you want ..

Comment: Not sure why you need a group by without an aggregate...  Do you have duplicate data and just need a distinct in the select  instead?

Comment: @xQbert Please see my update..

Comment: still don't see an aggregate. so unsure why you need the group by.... Do you want to order the results are you wanting to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: That doesnt really answer xQbert question: why do you GROUP BY ? Show the full queries please. Then, at first glance, if both GROUP BY returns the same results, it just means that col1 is never NULL and that col2 has the same value for every IDs

Comment: This is basically a sample query. I just wanted to know if query contains nvl, case statement, should I group by whole expression or just the columns

Comment: Some simple, sample data (4 or 5 rows) would go a long way to understanding what OP is really trying to do .... O.o

Comment: IMO: your initial question of : I am unsure which query is right. Anybody help me on this?  I would say neither.  As a group by shouldn't be used in this case.  Per your prior comment however, I would say use the same logic in the select as in the group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two queries will not necessarily give the same result. Which is correct depends on your requirement. Here is an example, using just the new `ADDRESS` column which you get by aggregating the input columns `ADD1` and `ADD2`.

Suppose in one row you have `ADD1 = 123 Main Street, Portland,` and `ADD2 = Oregon.` Then in the output, `ADDRESS = 123 Main Street, Portland, Oregon`

In another row you have `ADD1 = 123 Main Street,` and `ADD2 = Portland, Oregon`. For this row, the resulting `ADDRESS` is the same.

If you group by `ADDRESS` the two output rows will land in the same group, but if you group by `ADD1, ADD2` they will be in different groups. In this example it is likely you want to group by `ADDRESS`, but in other, similar-structure cases that wouldn't be what you want or need.

Answer (score 3):

Always try to implement all the columns (with same format) that you mentioned in the select statement in "Group By" except aggregated columns. In your case I would prefer the second approach.

```
SELECT id
    ,NAME
    ,add1 || ' ' || add2 address
    ,CASE 
        WHEN subId = 1
            THEN 'Maths'
        ELSE 'Science'
        END
    ,nvl(col1, col2) sampleCol
FROM Student_tbl
WHERE department = 'Student'
GROUP BY id
    ,NAME
    ,add1 || ' ' || add2
    ,CASE 
        WHEN subId = 1
            THEN 'Maths'
        ELSE 'Science'
        END
    ,nvl(col1, col2)
```

I can't see any aggregated columns in your Select. If your select does not require aggregation then you can simply get rid off group by. You can implement distinct in case of any duplicate records in your result set.

Answer (score 1):

After your last comment I THINK to finally understand what you are expecting from us.

Both queries are correct basically because for both approaches you've listed in your SELECT clause all the fields present in your GROUP BY clause

What you are doing is a bit strange here because the GROUP BY contains the `id`, I guess this is the unique identifier of each row so you are finally not grouping anything. You'll get as much as rows as your table contains.

The reason why it returns the same reults is purely data based. There might be scenarios where the 2 queries returns different results.

In your case, if it returns the same results, it would mean that `col1` is never `NULL`